# How to have a continuous stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, stroke

[image]

Can anybody help me have stroke of big rectangle(blue) for common part of the shapes? not red?
(First I drew big rectangle then the small one.Finally I colored them.). Thanks.

Comment: move the yellow/red rectangle earlier in the layer palette.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Best to visit the Adobe help site and learn [about layers and how they work](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/layers.html).

Answer (score 2):

- Click to select the yellow shape.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.
- In case the shortcut doesn't work for some reason, the same result is achieved by right-clicking on the yellow shape and choosing `Arrange → Send to Back`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked well. Thanks.

Comment: This shortcut is by the way quite impossible on international keyboards